# Generate data between two range date by some values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 dates, `StartDate` and `EndDate`:

```
Declare @StartDate date='2018/01/01', @Enddate date ='2018/12/31'
```

Then there is some data with a `date` and `value` in a mytable table:

```
----------------------------
 ID    date          value
----------------------------
  1  2018/02/14      4
  2  2018/09/26      7
  3  2017/09/20      2
```

data maybe start before 2018 and if it exist before @startdate get before values
else get 0
I'm looking to get a result that looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------
fromdate      todate       value
-----------------------------------
2018/01/01    2018/02/13     2
2018/02/14    2018/09/25     4
2018/09/26    2018/12/31     7
```

The first `fromdate` comes from `@StartDate` and the last `todate` is from `@Enddate`, and the other data should be generated.

I'm hoping to get this in an SQL query. I use sql-server 2016

Comment: What SQL server version do you use? Window functions will come in handy.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like a gaps and islands question.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as 
(
    select 0 as row_num, @StartDate as start_date, 0 as val
    UNION
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY start_date) as row_num, * from input
)
select curr.start_date 
  , DATEADD(day,-1,ISNULL(nex.start_date,DATEADD(day,1,@Enddate))) as end_date 
  , curr.val 
from cte curr
left join cte nex on curr.row_num = nex.row_num - 1;
```

You can find the simulation here: https://rextester.com/EIAXW23839

Comment: Shame that this answer was too downvoted without comment; especially when the OP has taken to time to show the example works.

Comment: this will genarate wrong result if our data start before 2018 like this :    insert into input values ('2017-02-14',4),('2018-09-26',7);

Comment: @Alavi my point in my below answer stands. if you don't provide us data from 2017, how do *we* know that it's there? We can't see your data.

Comment: data will create by users in application life time , maybe they define before date, i mean if there is no data before the value must be 0 and if its exist get value

Comment: would like to know why i am getting down votes here. Doesn't the start and end dates mean the data will be lying in between? is my understanding wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CTE to create your full range of dates, and then `LEAD` to create the `ToDate` column:

```
DECLARE @FromDate date = '20180101',
        @ToDate date = '20181231';


WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           CONVERT(date,[date]) [date], --This is why using keywords for column names is a bad idea
           [value]
    FROM (VALUES(1,'20180214',4),
                (2,'20180926',7),
                (3,'20170314',4))V(ID,[date],[value])),
Dates AS(
    SELECT [date]
    FROM VTE V
    WHERE V.[date] BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [date]
    FROM (VALUES(@FromDate))V([date]))
SELECT D.[date] AS FromDate,
       LEAD(DATEADD(DAY, -1,D.[date]),1,@ToDate) OVER (ORDER BY D.[date]) AS ToDate,
       ISNULL(V.[value],0) AS [value]
FROM Dates D
     LEFT JOIN VTE V ON D.[date] = V.[date];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=76f9b8da31c9ccb9f58babf7a3c5c28c)

Comment: this will wrong result when user add values before 2018 like (1,'20170314',4) this will cause wrong result

Comment: This is why full sample data in important @Alavi ; none of your data has a value with a value from 2017. If you have data from 2017, or other years, you should be including samples in your data. I've added a further clause to the `ON` which *should* work, but without full sample data, it's not tested.

Comment: OK, now tested by adding more representative data, @Alavi. Please remember, when asking questions in the future, to provide data that represents the data you have, not the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is cool just a little wrong in first data (01/01/2018 00:00:00 13/02/2018 00:00:00 0) value of first data is 0 but should be 4 because of this (3,'20170314',4) old data value before @FromDate is 4

Comment: @Alavi your first row in your expected results has a value of 0 in your question. Why is `0` wrong, is that;s what you have in your question. You need to fix your question before anyone can begin to help you any more.